# Why ONLY my cycle div's stopped working on my page?

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

http://4evergreengroup.com
username: user
password: user

Please someone review all my jquery cycle plugin div's stopped working all of a sudden, out of nowhere literally

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a comma on line 923 of jquery.cycle.all.js:

```
aspect:        false
```

should be

```
aspect:        false,
```

BTW, next time, check the javascript error console. It told me exactly what and where your error was:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cycle'
```

Line #'s didn't copy, but you get the idea.

Comment: but I am getting the cycle file from github, its not even mine? and I never edited anything! :( :(

Comment: I suppose Malsup isnt so perfect! I just downloaded the plugin, THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: You're welcome. You can also thank me by voting my answer up and choosing it as the correct answer.